# Creating a tuple using a for loop.

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples

I'm new to Python, and while I've done some of the refresher on Codecademy, I'm having difficulty with this first task.

**"Task 1: Please open the code skeleton file “i772_assg1.py” and implement the function list_ele_idx(li). You must write a “for loop” that reads the elements of a list, and for each element you create a tuple (element,index) to record the element and its index(position) in the list. This function takes a list “li” as its argument. The return value of the function should be a list of (element, index) tuples. In the main method, I have written a test case for task 1. Please un-comment the test case and test your function."**

Here's what I'm trying, but I'm not getting anything. Any feedback will be greatly appreciated, as this is my first post on Stack Overflow!

```
def list_ele_idx(li):
    index = 0 # index
    element = [(5,3,2,6)]
    li = [] # initialze a list; you need to add a tuple that includes an element and its index to this list
    # your code here. You must use for loop to read items in li and add (item,index)tuples to the list lis
    for index in li:
        li.append((element, index))
    return li # return a list of tuples
```

Comment: was the line `element = [(5,3,2,6)]` given?

Comment: You are taking in `li` as a parameter and then ignoring it. You are assigning `index` to zero and then discarding it by using `index` as a loop variable. You are looping through an empty list. You are not doing anything to keep track of the index in the list.

Comment: No, it wasn't given. A skeleton code was given to us, and in it the 'test case' was provided as a definition of main' the function. Since the test case contains [5,3,2,6], which to seem like elements of a list, I created a list variable 'element'. 

Thanks for responding!

Comment: @khelwood. It's like I'm re-assigning 'li' and 'index' by re-using them? 

Now that I say it like that, it would sound like a blunder. -_-

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's walk through your code step by step so that you get an idea of the errors you are making, then let's look at a correct solution. Finally, let's look at the pythonic solution that might annoy your teacher.

The line

```
index = 0
```

is fine, because you want to start counting the indices at zero. The line

```
element = [(5,3,2,6)]
```

makes no sense, because your function should work for any given list, not just for your test case. So let's delete it.
You initialize your result list with

```
li = []
```

which would be fine if you would not re-use the name of the given input list `li` which is discarding the argument given to the function. Use

```
result = []
```

instead. Next your are looping over your now empty list `li` with

```
for index in li:
```

and since `li` is empty at this point, the loop body will never execute. Naming your loop variable `index` is confusing because you are looping over the elements of a list with that syntax, not over the indices.

```
li.append((element, index))
```

Inside your `for` loop is just wrong because you are never increasing `index` and `element` is a list, not a single element from your input list.

Here's a commented version of a working solution:

```
def list_ele_idx(li):
    index = 0 # start counting at index 0
    result = [] # initialize an empty result list
    for item in li: # loop over the items of the input list
        result.append((item, index)) # append a tuple of the current item and the current index to the result
        index += 1 # increment the index
    return result # return the result list when the loop is finished
```

Using `enumerate(li)` would give you a simpler solution, but I don't think that's in the spirit of the exercise. Anyway, the short solution is:

```
def list_ele_idx(li):
    return [(y,x) for x,y in enumerate(li)]
```

Comment: This is such a nice way to provide an answer! :-)

Comment: @timgeb Thank you for the descript response. The first thing that I should have noticed was a missing increment for the loop variable. 

We were given 'lis' in place of your declared variable 'result'. Being new to Python, I thought it was a typo and was completely unaware that using 'li' in the argument and as a definition would discard it. 

Thank you!

Comment: @squidvision If this answer solved your question be sure to [mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This helps any future visitors by showing them what answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Python's enumerate function, it gives you the element and its index to iterate over:

```
def list_ele_idx(li):
    tuple_list = []
    for index, item in enumerate(li):
        tuple_list.append((index, item))
    return tuple_list
```